# turf.js returning invalid coordinates

Tags: javascript, leaflet, turfjs

This code is part of a program that takes in addresses that a user enters in a search bar and tries to find them on a map. Here is a [link to the site.](http://digitalwaterfall.space/ypsilandlords/)

```
createSQL: function() {
    SearchableMapLib.currentPinpoint = [results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()];
    var address = $("#search-address").val();
    SearchableMapLib.currentResults = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(SearchableMapLib.geojsonData));
    
    if(SearchableMapLib.currentPinpoint != null && address != '') {           
        var point = turf.point([SearchableMapLib.currentPinpoint[1], SearchableMapLib.currentPinpoint[0]]);             
        var buffered = turf.buffer(point, SearchableMapLib.radius, {units: 'meters'});
        
        ///it breaks here at turf.pointsWithinPolygon
        SearchableMapLib.currentResults = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(SearchableMapLib.currentResults, buffered);
        
        if (SearchableMapLib.debug) {
          console.log('found points within')
          console.log(SearchableMapLib.currentResults);
        }
```

However, it tells me 'Uncaught Error: No valid coordinates'.

I am pretty sure the coordinates are valid. For example, when I enter `console.log('point: ' + SearchableMapLib.currentPinpoint[1] + ' ' + SearchableMapLib.currentPinpoint[0]);` it returns `point: -83.6235566 42.24362170000001`

Why is this error happening?

(I am new to javascript and did not write this code (it's based off a [template](https://github.com/datamade/searchable-map-template-csv)), let me know if any of this doesn't make sense.)